# Scheduled Task for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, vbscript, task

I'm trying to run a vbscript to execute a controller action (via URL) on a scheduled nightly basis. The script that I found here on SO is:

```
Call ScheduleTask() 

Sub ScheduleTask()
On Error Resume Next

Dim objRequest
Dim URL

Set objRequest = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
URL = "http://localhost/controller/action"

objRequest.open "GET", URL , false

objRequest.Send

Set objRequest = Nothing

End Sub
```

When I run the task, it never completes. It just gets hung up. Is this due to security issues? Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Run the script manually using `cscript` and see if it reports any errors.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction on how to do that? I'm a scripting novice...

Comment: Open a command-prompt and run `cscript foo.vbs` (where `foo.vbs` is your script name) and see what it prints to the console.

Comment: keeps saying invalid character. must be somewhere in the script file i guess?

Comment: The error message will tell you what line the error occurred on. Please paste the entire error message verbatim into your posting.

Comment: Got it! I had to create the script file in notepad. Thank you! How can I mark your answer?

Comment: How were you creating it otherwise?

Comment: I did a text file add within visual studio and pasted the code there. Apparently, that file wasn't the same as creating with Notepad.